# Nodejs Deployment on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

How can I containerize a Node.js application with a MySQL database and then deploy it on GKE using Bitbucket Pipeline and DockerHub? I need guidance on the steps and best practices to achieve this deployment successfully. Thanks in advance for any help from the community!

I am facing difficulty while creating the pipeline and deployment.yml file for GKE

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for help on this :

https://psspavan96.medium.com/ci-cd-for-node-js-application-using-google-cloud-part-1-5f7466df913d
DB you can configure separately using Cloud SQL and link it via service type config map and secrets in your image in k8s